# Why does the graph of compressibility factor(z) vs pressure increase after reaching the minimum?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

I understand why it decreases for most of the gases but i cannot understand why it increases after reaching a certain minimum.

Answer (score 2):

After a certain amount of pressure, the molecules start repelling each other and this leads to a rise in compressibility factor.

At high pressures, the van der Wall constant $b$ which represents the finite volume occupied by the gas molecules plays a greater role than the van der Wall constant $a$ which represents the attractive forces between the gas molecules.